# unit testing $window.location.reload() in angular

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, window, karma-jasmine

I do a `$window.location.reload()` in my controller that only injects `$window` which means it throws the following error:

> Some of your tests did a full page reload!

In order to get rid of this, you are supposed to mock the window object however i get the following error:

> TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 't.location.reload()')

my test looks like this:

```
var authController,
    window = {'location': {}};

beforeEach(inject(function($controller) {
    authController = $controller('AuthController', {
        $window: window
    });
}));
```

there must be something obvious i'm doing wrong that i can't spot as i'm doing this on another test pretty much identical and it works fine. any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to use a spy on `$window.location.reload()`

```
beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $window) {
    spyOn($window.location, 'reload');
    authController = $controller('AuthController');
}));
```

Comment: This doesn't work, it throws an error "reload is not declared writable or has no setter."